# How to change the backgroundimage of a button programmaticaly when touching?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, background, uibutton

I have an IPhone application in which I am using an `IBOutlet` button with a background. On its click, I call a webservice and on the success of that, I need to change the background of the button. Now I am doing it in this way but nothing's happening:

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"follow_shop.png"];
[following setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done in code is correct. You can do three things now (in decreasing order of probability of finding the issue):

1) Check in your IB if initially, you have set its `image` or `backgroundImage`. The two are different and `image` comes above the `backgroundImage`(effectively rendering `backgroundImage` as being hidden). Both of these (the image you set in IB and in code) should be either one (`image` or `backgroundImage`).

2) Check if `follow_shop.png` is the correct name. You can also use breakpoints to see if `buttonImage` has memory or not.

3) Check if `following` is connected in your IB.

Comment: Correct me if i'm mistaken, but i think he might also need to set the button type to custom. Not sure though.

Comment: @tomi2711 You are absolutely right in thinking that but it's his choice and is not relevant to the problem because he can already see his image set through `IB`!

Comment: yes, but I thought that maybe the background image wouldn't should if the button type was rounded rect. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

1. Look if your `IBOutlet` is connected properly (e.g. using `NSLog(@"%@",following);`)
2. Re-Add your image (e.g. using `Copy files into destination groups folder`)
3. Have a look at your target. Is your image in `Copy Bundle Resources`?

Answer (score 0):

Have an `IBOutlet` for the button and in your `IBAction` put this code

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```